# Printer Loading on Terminal Services - Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, windows-terminal-services

We have a problem with one of our clients where the default printer he uses isn't loaded by the time the app that he uses over terminal services is launched. If you check again a minute later the printer is there but the app reads the default printer at the time of launch.

Is it possible to get the login process to delay till all printers are loaded?

The user is in a remote location so we have no direct access to the printers.

Comment: How exactly is the user printing?  Is the client coming from a local network, or external?  Is he printing through the RDP client, is the printer being added by a script while they connect?

Comment: External network, printing through the RDP client. The printers are being handled by the Remote Desktop client, not a script.

Answer (score 0):

We 'fixed' this issue (slow printer mappings) by adding the printers locally to our terminal servers (Not going through a print server).  That doesn't directly answer your question of 'how to make login seem slower', but it does somewhat resolves your original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set up his app shortcut if he uses that method or the setting in TS to run the app on startup to use one of the "timer tools" (wait.exe is an oldie that comes to mind) to delay the start of the app?  e.g. set up a command file that will run "wait 60" and then "c:\program.exe"